# Recent activity page: reputation not displaying properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation isn't being displayed on recent activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/reputation-isnt-being-displayed-on-recent-activity-page)

If I go to my [recent activity report on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?StartDate=2011-02-03&EndDate=2011-02-03), I get the reputation total, but no list of the votes received. Same problem with [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?StartDate=2011-02-02&EndDate=2011-02-02), [this week](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?StartDate=2011-01-30&EndDate=2011-02-03) (I do get the listing for a vote cast on my *question*), [last week](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-01-23&EndDate=2011-01-29), [this month](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-02-01&EndDate=2011-02-03), and [last month](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-01-01&EndDate=2011-01-31) (which *does* display reputation down due to a downvote on a question). It seems, then, to only be displaying activity related to questions, not to answers.

Comment: Same on p.se since today

Comment: @Nick Craver: Just out of curiosity: the "exact duplicate" was posted *after* I posted this question. Shouldn't the *other one* be the one labeled an "exact duplicate"?

Comment: yes, if I had seen this one first...but I had been up 22 hours and saw/answered the other before this, sorry!

Comment: @Nick Craver: No problem. I think I forgot to add the smiley to the previous comment... Thanks for fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in `2011.2.3.6` (at least on SO).