# Reputation isn't being displayed on recent activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, recent-activity

I can see today's reputation is **50** but no detail available in this page. I tried clicking the tab 2-3 times; it used to show detailed data there.

[image: Screenshot of the reputation tab]

Comment: Confirmed: I see the same lack of detail in all my reputation pages for various SO/SU/SF/SE sites.

Comment: This is a dup of [this earlier question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/recent-activity-page-reputation-not-displaying-properly).

Comment: @Dennis: Since this one got answered while the other one wasn't, I suppose closing this one as a dupe would be stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug related to moving some database tables around tonight and me forgetting `Left` here for answers (which have no ViewCount).  It's resolved now and has been deployed to all sites in the network.

Comment: Oh, right, you solved it while I was typing my answer!

Comment: can you describe bit more the issue

Comment: @org.life.java - Sure!, the way we store ViewCount is very expensive in terms of the update frequency, this was moved to another location (and caching tiers, etc), so it needs to be Left joined since that new table doesn't have answers (they don't have views, questions do), without the left join answers were inadvertently being excluded here.

Comment: ok. and  `we store ViewCount is very expensive in terms of the update frequency,` how do you maintain this. yo  cache count and update it to DB at certain interval or what strategy used

Comment: @org.life.java - very carefully :) Kevin Montrose who wrote our cache layer (and our resident redis expert) has an excellent post here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172

Comment: @Nick *kool* :) :) ,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's more complicated than that. It seems it does show all the negative rep, and it shows the positive rep gained for questions. Here's the data for me since Jan, 1st:

[image]

Comment: It was seeing only questions (not answers) was the actual issue, positive/negative was just coincidence in your case :)

Comment: @Nick: Ah, I see. On the bright side, it was interesting to see all the down-votes I made to questions for a month accumulated as such. Usually they are drowned and don't show up. `:)`