# Dates timeline on Recent activity

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity

a little weird this morning

[image]

shouldn't that have a different day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the times you'll see it's 12:00:00AM to 11:59:59PM (UTC) on that same day, so the duration is in fact a full 24 hours, it just *appears* one second shorter until you think about it a bit :)

Comment: so, but where is my reputation description? as it says `10`, it should appear that upvote answer/question right?

Comment: @balexandre - that's actually a separate issue I just resolved, you can see the thread here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77649

Comment: @balexandre - It should be fixed now. Check out [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/reputation-isnt-being-displayed-on-recent-activity-page)